# Django 4 backport old Oracle 12 support

Tags: python, django, oracle

Django 4.0 release notes
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/releases/4.0/#dropped-support-for-oracle-12-2-and-18c

says:

> Dropped support for Oracle 12.2 and 18c¶
>
> Upstream support for Oracle 12.2 ends in March 2022 and for Oracle 18c
> it ends in June 2021. Django 3.2 will be supported until April 2024.
> Django 4.0 officially supports Oracle 19c.

So, what if I will use this simple backend for continue to use oracle 12 as secondary data sourse **just for select** from it, is it may cause any problems?

```
from django.db.backends.oracle.base import DatabaseWrapper as DatabaseWrapperOracle
from django.db.utils import NotSupportedError


class DatabaseWrapper(DatabaseWrapperOracle):
    def check_database_version_supported(self):
        try:
            super().check_database_version_supported()
        except NotSupportedError as e:
            pass  # Oracle 19 or later is required (found 12.1.0.2.0).
```

Please share your experience

*DatabaseWrapper seems works fine

Comment: What a reason for close vote?, show off your mind

Answer (score -1):

So, ignoring NotSupportedError works in prod.

I am using only selects from tables and views.

- Python 3.11
- Django 4.2
- cx-Oracle==7.3.0
- oracle 12.1.0.2.0

Comment: *do not forget to write what is wrong when minus or write answer